# pivot varchar columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I tried to get some result into a pivot table but not get the expected result.Here by I have put the code and result.

```
DECLARE @TblIdeaCategory TABLE 
(
IdeaImplement varchar(2000),
IdeaCategory varchar(2000)
)

INSERT INTO @TblIdeaCategory values('Metrics Feedback One  #1','MetricFeedback')
INSERT INTO @TblIdeaCategory values('Metrics Feedback Two #1','MetricFeedback')
INSERT INTO @TblIdeaCategory values('Analysis Feedback One #1','AnalysisFeedback')
INSERT INTO @TblIdeaCategory values('Analysis Feedback Two #1','AnalysisFeedback')
INSERT INTO @TblIdeaCategory values('Idea Generation Feedback One #1','IdeaGenerationFeedback')
INSERT INTO @TblIdeaCategory values('Idea Generation Feedback Two #1','IdeaGenerationFeedback')


select 
 IdeaGenerationFeedback,AnalysisFeedback,MetricFeedback from 

(select IdeaImplement,IdeaCategory
 from  @TblIdeaCategory as board
 ) resultTable
pivot (
 max(IdeaImplement)  for IdeaCategory in (IdeaGenerationFeedback,AnalysisFeedback,MetricFeedback))  as resultpivot


 select  IdeaImplement,IdeaCategory from @TblIdeaCategory
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: Ex : MetricsFeedBack : Under MetricsFeedBack column need two row : 1.Metrics Feedback One  #1 2.Metrics Feedback Two #1

Comment: I've provided an answer which gets you the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should do what you want:

```
DECLARE @TblIdeaCategory TABLE 
(
IdeaImplement varchar(2000),
IdeaCategory varchar(2000)
)

INSERT INTO @TblIdeaCategory values('Metrics Feedback One  #1','MetricFeedback')
INSERT INTO @TblIdeaCategory values('Metrics Feedback Two #1','MetricFeedback')
INSERT INTO @TblIdeaCategory values('Analysis Feedback One #1','AnalysisFeedback')
INSERT INTO @TblIdeaCategory values('Analysis Feedback Two #1','AnalysisFeedback')
INSERT INTO @TblIdeaCategory values('Idea Generation Feedback One #1','IdeaGenerationFeedback')
INSERT INTO @TblIdeaCategory values('Idea Generation Feedback Two #1','IdeaGenerationFeedback')


select 
 IdeaGenerationFeedback,AnalysisFeedback,MetricFeedback from 

(select IdeaImplement,IdeaCategory,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY IdeaCategory ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RNO
 from  @TblIdeaCategory as board
 ) resultTable
pivot (
MAX(IdeaImplement)  for IdeaCategory in (IdeaGenerationFeedback,AnalysisFeedback,MetricFeedback))  as resultpivot
```

The result is as below,

```
IdeaGenerationFeedback            AnalysisFeedback           MetricFeedback
Idea Generation Feedback One #1   Analysis Feedback One #1   Metrics Feedback One #1
Idea Generation Feedback Two #1   Analysis Feedback Two #1   Metrics Feedback Two #1
```

Comment: The PIVOT function requires an aggregation to get it to work. I've created a Row ID partitioned across IdeaCategory so MAX would be computed across each levels.

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually would want to use `UNPIVOT` here rather than `PIVOT`, but in any case you could just use a series of unions, which might perform better anyway.

```
SELECT IdeaGenerationFeedback AS IdeaImplement, 'IdeaGenerationFeedback' AS IdeaCategory
FROM yourOriginalTable
UNION ALL
SELECT AnalysisFeedback, 'AnalysisFeedback' FROM yourOriginalTable
UNION ALL
SELECT MetricFeedback, 'MetricFeedback' FROM yourOriginalTable;
```

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
Invalid column name 'IdeaGenerationFeedback'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 33
Invalid column name 'AnalysisFeedback'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
Invalid column name 'MetricFeedback'.        Throwing error

Comment: My query should if run against the table whose screenshot is showed as the very first thing in your question.